# Store function return values in igraph objects in R

Tags: r, igraph

I have a function that returns an igraph object named readFn() . I want to call this function using a for loop and store result

```
files <- c("345","456")

for(i in files){
  g <- readFn(i) 
}

#Error: object 'g' not found
#In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first #50)


readFn <- function(i) {
#some lines
graph #graph -> is an igraph object to be returned to for loop
}
```

I want to get 2 graphs in igraph objects named g_345 and g_456

Comment: Try `g <- lapply(files, readFn)`

Comment: Your `g` should be preassigned to a `list` i.e. `g <- vector('list', length(files))`. inside the for loop `for(i in seq_along(files) g[[i]] <- readFn(files[i])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using *lapply*:

```
library(igraph)

# example function that returns igraph object
readFn <- function(i) {
  graph.empty(n = 2)
  }

files <- c("345","456")

g <- lapply(files , readFn)

# assign names
names(g) <- paste0("g_", files)
```

Then we can access each *graph* by name:

```
g$g_345

# IGRAPH 598e70c D--- 2 0 -- 
# + edges from 598e70c:
```